# Deploy DropWizard to Azure

Tags: azure, deployment, jar, jetty, dropwizard

I did not find any recent tutorial on DropWizard on Azure, the only one I found (https://github.com/AzureCAT-GSI/DropWizardOnAzure) is outdated. Something is missing.

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
    <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
        arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\TestWebService-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar&quot;  -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%   &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\config.yml&quot;">
    </httpPlatform>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

config.yml

```
logging:
  level: INFO
  loggers:
    com.TestWebService: DEBUG
```

I have deployed web.config, config.yml and .jar into wwwroot.

The outcome is always 503.

How to even debug it? I have enabled and checked logs - nothing useful.

Linux appservice also returns error.

Comment: I've tried checking the Microsoft Azure documentation and it is hard for me to find the `web.config` examples and documentation. However there is a recently published [guide with Spring Boot sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-app-with-maven-plugin?view=azure-java-stable#). It is using a Microsoft provided `Maven` plug-in for the app definition in Azure and the actual deployment.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I ended up with Spring Boot as an intermediate solution. But DropWizard would make more sense for me as I use it anyways.

Comment: I meant that it should be possible to use the `Spring Boot` sample as a guideline. The deployment steps and setting should be the same - in both cases the deployment artefact is a runnable `JAR` file. The only critical step missing in the guide is the configuration for the external configuration file and the additional `command` parameter for the Dropwizard application. How to achieve this is shown only in the archived example. You should contact Microsoft support about this.

Comment: ah, good point, thanks!